# Google Drive API for Android - CreateFile succeeds, but no file is sent to cloud

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-drive-android-api

I am integrating my Xamarin.Android app with Google Drive API. My main problem is that even though all API calls ends up with success, some of my binary files are not persisted in Google Drive.

I try to send 5-10 of audio files (wav, mp3, ogg, etc) sized 10-80 MB each.
Here's my approach of sending binary files:

```
                string mimeType = GetMimeType(localFilePath);
                string fullSourceFilePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilePath);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[BinaryStreamsBufferLength];

                using (var contentResults = await DriveClass.DriveApi.NewDriveContentsAsync(_googleApiClient).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    if (contentResults.Status.IsSuccess) //always returns true
                    {
                        using (var readStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fullSourceFilePath))
                        {
                            using (var fileChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                               .SetTitle(path[1])
                               .SetMimeType(mimeType)
                               .Build())
                            {
                                using (var writeStream = new BinaryWriter(contentResults.DriveContents.OutputStream))
                                {
                                    int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, BinaryStreamsBufferLength);

                                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                                    {
                                        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                        bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, BinaryStreamsBufferLength);
                                    }

                                    writeStream.Close();
                                }

                                readStream.Close();

                                var singleFileCopyResult = await targetCloudFolder.CreateFileAsync(_googleApiClient, fileChangeSet, contentResults.DriveContents,
                                    new ExecutionOptions.Builder().SetConflictStrategy(ExecutionOptions.ConflictStrategyOverwriteRemote).Build()).ConfigureAwait(false);

                                return singleFileCopyResult.Status.IsSuccess; //always returns true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Above method is called in foreach loop with list of locally stored files that needs to be sent.

Also, when connecting to API for the first time, I requestSync:

```
if (_isSyncRequired)
            syncResult = await DriveClass.DriveApi.RequestSyncAsync(_googleApiClient).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I am already after few days of trying various solutions including:
- changing stream types
- changing order of API method calls
- using non-Async API methods (which in fact are also async)
- experimented with different overloads and parameters when possible
- tried to refactor to non-obsolete API calls (impossible to do as it requires ultra-heavy GoogleSignIn NuGet with tons of dependencies and my app is heavy enough)

None of above worked and my files are later successfully downloaded in like 80% of all files being sent (all upload statuses are success).

Does anyone of you experienced similar issues so far? Do you have any tips what can be done in order to make file downloadable if all upload methods claims everything succeeds?

Many thanks in advance for any clues :)

Comment: Is your `fullSourceFilePath` within your app's sandbox? Is it a content provider based url or a file:// based one? And are you getting a zero byte result in Drive or no file at all.

Comment: `fullSourceFilePath` is always available as it is app sandboxed file. I do not have any content providers because I use only AppFolder drive scope and no user can directly see files being sent. Bytes of all files are correctly sent, but when I later retrieve them using `driveFolder.ListChildrenAsync`, in 80-90% of cases only a subset of sent files is listed.